# Rolling back transactions mariadb when they takes too long

Tags: locking, mariadb

I have a code in php, that open an transaction, do some queries and commits.
Calling this code 5 times in the same second causes 4 transaction to be created and they doesn't finish.
Some locks are created (metadata locks) 
and those transaction can stay "live" for minutes (if I run it once - it ends in less than 10 seconds)

My Question -Is there a way to force a rollback on those transaction from the database side - if a transaction is lasting more than 15 seconds ?

in the processlist I see those process are "sleeping" but the locks remains and holds any other write activity on the site, which kills it.

Comment: Give us some clues of the code.  Are you `UPDATEing` all million rows of a single table?

Comment: transaction contain DDL....

Comment: Caution!  DDL statements cause a `COMMIT`!  Let's see more details of the transaction.